# scan receipts with a GUI

Tags: scanning, ocr

I'm new to ubuntu, and I'm trying to find an application to scan my receipts in order to create an expense report. Is there any software available? Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Simple Scan.  Its an easy application to use, and it included in Ubuntu.  Just click on dash, search for simple, and then click on Simple Scan.  Happy scanning.

[image]

Simple Scan doesn't have OCR capabilities.  For OCR you can try [Tesseract](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-ocr.html),  [Lios](http://code.google.com/p/linux-intelligent-ocr-solution/), or [Clara OC](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/clara)R.

Comment: Can Simple scan OCR the receipt?

Comment: I just added that info in the answer.